# How to fetch "name" property from an array if i know its corresponding "id"

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a simple array with id and name. If i know the id then how can i fetch the name, array is shown below:

```
var dataobj = [
  {id:1,name:"Jessica"},
{id:2,name:"Tom"},
{id:3,name:"Will"}
];
```

i have the `id` for example **2** with me in a variable, how can i get the **name** which belongs to this id ?

I have `clickedID=2` value in my slist.component.ts and i want to fetch its corresponding `name`, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log the name which belongs to the id 2, it's as simple as following :

```
 let obj = dataobj.find(obj => obj.id === 2);
 console.log(obj.name);
```

Comment: It worked, trying to use the same technique but getting error, here is my code - https://pastebin.com/mf2rSDri , see line 46,47  , in console.log `this.array_no1` is showing this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj6qjf5tvp9dfy1/Screenshot%202017-05-29%2000.50.07.png?dl=0 , objects are shwing up in console but filter is not working, unable to get the `description` of the corresponding id

Comment: Try to replace === by == and let me kow.

Comment: worked thanks but why `==` worked and `===` didnt ??

Comment: Actually I think your id isn't a number but a string. So you compare a string with a number. The === return false but the == return true. You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript) for more informations about the equals operators.

Answer (score 0):

you can use es6 array syntax:

```
dataobj.find(el => el.id === 2)
```

output:

```
Object {id: 2, name: "Tom"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array find method

```
    const secondItem = dataObj.find(function (item){
     return item.id === 2;
})
```

Then name can be accessed as

```
secondItem.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something more readable and reusable with a dynamic find

```js
var dataobj = [
{id:1,name:"Jessica"},
{id:2,name:"Tom"},
{id:3,name:"Will"}
];

let getNameFromObjId = obj => id  => obj.find(x=> x.id===id).name; 
console.log(getNameFromObjId(dataobj)(2))
```